# Amazon S3 - Bucket Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Having a heck of a time setting up a referer policy from my url to have access to an Amazon S3 bucket.

I can get it to work with my *.myurl.com/* but anytime the request from a secure https request, my access is denied even with the wild card.

Thanks

Edit: Rushed my first initial post, here's more detail.

I have a bucket policy on amazon s3 that only allows access if it comes from my url(s).

```
"aws:Referer": [
                    "*.myurl.com/*",
                    "*.app.dev:3000/*" ]
```

This referer policy correctly only allows connections from my dev environment and also my staging url if accessed via http. However, if the user is located at https://www.myurl.com/* they are denied access from Amazon.

Is there a way to allow https connections to Amazon S3? Is it my Bucket Policy? I've tried hard coding the https url into the bucket policy, but this did not do the trick.

Sorry about being overly brief.

Comment: you have to explain bit better your problem.

Comment: Try this `"StringLike":{"aws:Referer": [
                    "*.myurl.com/*",
                    "*.app.dev:3000/*" ]}`

Comment: Another thing: check how the `Referer` header in the https request looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the help last night, sorry I ended up falling asleep. The issues I was having were not related to the bucket policy. If someone finds this and has a similar problem, for me personally I was using a Ruby Gem to handle the uploading of files called Carrierwave. I did not have Carrierwave configured to force SSL. Once forcing SSL my get and put requests required an https connection rather than simply being http.

Answer (score 1):

From the [HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.1.3):

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a
> Referer header field in a (non-secure)
> HTTP request if the referring page was
> transferred with a secure    protocol.